# How to programmatically wipe SD on android

Tags: android, device-admin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete entire contents of sdcard programmatically in Andriod 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006811/how-to-delete-entire-contents-of-sdcard-programmatically-in-andriod-2-2)

I have a security app and currently I am using DeviceAdminReceiver to wipe the phone when user request. DeviceAdminReceiver did wipe the phone successful, however not the sd card.

Anyone know how to programmatically wipe SD on android?
Thanks.