# How to delete all the files from sd card in android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete entire contents of sdcard programmatically in Android 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006811/how-to-delete-entire-contents-of-sdcard-programmatically-in-android-2-2)

I want to **clear all the files from android device programmatically**.

Can anyone suggest me the way or code, Hence I can perform this operation please...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if( path.exists() ) {
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
                if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
                    deleteDirectory(files[i]);
                }
                else {
                    files[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
        return(path.delete());
    }
```

add the code just call it when ever you require using the path of the directory to delete or the file to delete

Comment: If you copy-paste from an [external source](http://www.developerfeed.com/io/snippet/how-recursively-delete-file-directory), you might as well add a reference to it.

Comment: @MH might have been copied long back but it was the code of project which i was using so just pasted it